# strings union without duplicating numbers

Tags: string, union

```
#include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
        string s1="123"; //Set up string 1
        string s2="356"; //Set up string 2
        string s3;       //Setup string 3
```

this code should print the result 12356.

Comment: Did you write the code or was it provided to you? It looks like a homework assignment or test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "loop through s3" code is empty. You should do some checking inside your loop. You should also set `is_c_in_s3` to `false` before the loop, and check for it to be `false` after the loop.

```
bool is_c_in_s3=false;
for(int j=0;j<s3.size();j++){    //Loop though s3
    if (c == s3[j]) {
        is_c_in_s3=true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!is_c_in_s3) {
    s3+=c; //Add the element to String 3
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do that a lot of time but you do for a few minutes. congratulations. thank you a lot. I am studying c# for a while. I will try to do this in C#. If I had some problem, could I call you? thank you once again

Comment: @MIKI No problem, this site can get you help with simple issues like this in a matter of minutes. Sometimes when you stare at the same problem for too long you fail to notice an obvious bug. But someone with a fresh look can spot it in a matter of seconds.

Comment: I tried to do something in c# but, please look into the code, if you have time to help me. thanks

Comment: @MIKI As far as that other question is concerned, you've got a great answer from the top guy on this site! If you would like him to change the answer, you need to edit the question, and mention the additional requirements (e.g. to not use LINQ).